# Probably a error on CSS/JS - MultiLanguage Site

Tags: javascript, php, css

Im creating a new multi-language site and works perfectly.
The problem is when I change to site.com/news to site.com/en/news, the css/js (I don't know) just stop showing - or maybe is a error on bad format or something like that on php? -.

In order to you guys understand it better (site.com/en/news):
  http://i.epvpimg.com/04K2aab.png

This is the part of índex when the client clicks it in order to go to /news:

```
<?php print $lang;?>/news"><?=$text['start'];?>
```

My folder of languages is like this:

```
lang/en/lang.en.php
lang/pt/lang.pt.php
```

And this are my part of índex.php:

```
require_once 'inc/function.php'; 
require_once 'inc/config.php';
require_once("lang/lang.all.php");
require ('inc/pages.php');

require_once("lang/".$lang."/lang.".$lang.".php");
```

Comment: Make sure the css and js reference the full path, not the relative path: ie, make sure it starts with a slash. `/path/to/file.css`

Comment: They are reference in full path (I think):
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.superslides.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="js/datatables.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

Comment: Nope. See, there's no slash before the js folder. Change it to `<script src="/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js">`

Comment: Oh dude, you are the man! Thank you very much!

Comment: Btw, do you know a solution to save the session from the client? For example: Now, if a switch to portuguese but I go to /news, it goes back to english, is there any solution?

Comment: Probably save the language in `$_SESSION`, then you can check against that any time you need to check the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always a good idea to have vales such as Site Url or Sys Path declared as constants in a config file so you can call js/css with full path and domain. 
Consider adding to your config file

```
define("SITEURL", "http://yoursite.com");
```

This allows you to then call js/css using that constant

```
<script src="<?=SITEURL?>/js/jquery.superslides.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: Also, be sure to review your source code in browser and click in js/css to make sure you are pointing them properly

Comment: Now my question is about subfolder. I want to do like site.com/en/news but it returns me to the default page. Anny solution?